# Is it possible to emulate a mobile device without javascript in Puppeteer?

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer

I'm running e2e tests with puppeteer and one of the use cases is "mobile browser without javascript", is there a way to emulate a device with no javascript?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to turn Javascript on or off: [page.setJavaScriptEnabled](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetjavascriptenabledenabled)

```
await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false)
```

It must be used before going to a target page:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const iPhone = puppeteer.devices['iPhone 6'];

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.emulate(iPhone);

  await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false); // <-- disable javascript

  await page.goto('https://www.enable-javascript.com/', {waituntil : 'domcontentloaded'});
  await page.evaluate(() => {
      document.querySelector('.disabled').scrollIntoView(); // scroll to message about javascript status 
  })
  await page.screenshot({ path : 'screenshot.jpg' });
  await browser.close();
});
```

And the result is - javascript disabled and the emulation is applied:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n02sQ.jpg